# Was Brett egg morphing?

Tags: alien-franchise

In a deleted scene in Alien we see that Dallas and Brett are cocooned.

Brett is now more of a egg shape and appears to be in horrible condition. Dallas is starting to look like Brett, but isn't as egg-shaped.

**Was Brett morphing into an egg?**

Answer (score 8):

Yes, Brett was morphing into an egg.

The existence of this scene was first mentioned in [The Book of Alien](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/The_Book_of_Alien), a book from behind the scenes of the production of the film. Two pieces of concept art of the scene is described like this on page 97:

> An arresting sequence omitted from the final version: **the Alien weaves cocoons around its victims' bodies. Objective: more Alien eggs**.

The scene also appears in the [novelization](http://avp.wikia.com/wiki/Alien_(novel)) of the movie by Alan Dean Foster.

> *'Kill me,' the whisperer pleaded with her.
>
>   'What . . . what did it do to you?'
>
>   Dallas tried to speak again, failed. His head turned a little to the right. Ripley swung her light, turned it upward slightly. **A second cocoon hung there, different in texture and colour from the first. It was smaller and darker, the silk having formed a hard, shining shell. It looked, although Ripley couldn't know it, like the broken, empty urn on the derelict ship.***

Comment: Wow, the franchise would've been so much creepier with this detail left intact.  Of course, it would have implied a different tack down the line via-a-vis the alien queen and the whole Resurrection movie, but I'm not convinced that's a bad thing.

Comment: @Valorum Thanks for fetching the quote!

Comment: @tobiasvl - No worries. I was going to use them in my own answer but I realised you'd already covered this in yours